# Little tricky mod rewrite request

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So this is what I currently have ruled.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ paste.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Url is like this.
http://website.com/pasteid

What I'm trying to do though is have 
example.com/pasteid/download
 OR 
example.com/pasteid/plain

the GET parameters I'm passing for download / plain are a=download / a=plain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you would like to access your site like this:

http://website.com/pasteid/download

If I well understand you, you want this in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)$ paste.php?p=$1&a=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ paste.php?p=$1 [L]
```

It does this:

```
http://www.example.com/pasteid/download => /paste.php?p=pasteid&a=download
http://www.example.com/pasteid/plain => /paste.php?p=pasteid&a=plain
```

The full set of rules let resource files unrewritten (css, js, png, jpg).

Comment: No no, pasteid is a dynamic example.

Comment: Get would be: website.com/paste.php?p=pasteid&a=download OR plain

Comment: Please give an example how (which URL) you would like to access your site with params?

Comment: website.com/paste.php?p=pasteid&a=download

so like: website.com/pasteid/download

Comment: Thanks man for the update worked like a charm. Marked as answer.